# Doubt regarding the macroscopic version of the electrostatic energy

Tags: electrostatics, energy-conservation, work, self-energy

Some caveats before you start reading:

The averaging procedure I subscribe to when bringing out the macroscopic Maxwell's equations from the microscopic ones(to a decent approximation in preserving the Maxwell's laws in somewhat uniform media) is Rusakoff's statistical averaging (using weight functions).

I don't mind the Lorenz averaging technique for systems with considerable uniformity.

With that out of the way, Consider a purely electrostatic situation, we know that given a system of point charges, whose charge distribution is given by $\rho=\Sigma q_{i} \delta(r^\prime - r_{i} ^\prime)$, one can easily find the exact work done to assemble this configuration to be $$W=\frac{1}{2}\Sigma q_{i} V(r_{i})$$

Where $V(r_{i})$ denotes the potential (the exact one, calculated using microscopic quantities) at the point $r_{i}$ (it is understood that at $r_{i}$ where the charge $q_{i}$ is placed, it's own contribution is not counted). This discrete sum formula takes no hit when converted to the integral: $$W=\frac{1}{2} \iiint \rho_{micro}(r^\prime)V_{micro}(r^\prime)d\tau^\prime$$
*Provided* we keep the quantities inside to be the *microscopic* ones. Within the framework of classical Electrostatics, I consider this formula to be exact. But we hardly ever deal with the *microscopic* charge distributions or quantities. We have only access to the macroscopic stuff, and hence the formula we write down for the electrostatic energy with macroscopic variables: $$W \stackrel{?}{=}\frac{1}{2} \iiint \rho_{macro}(r^\prime)V_{macro}(r^\prime)d\tau^\prime$$may or may not give us exact values (I couldn't do the calculation, for it required evaluating weighted integrals inside integrals. The situation appeared hopelessly complicated. After a lot of thought I realised that **IF** I am able to show that given a chunk of charge, in the presence of an external electric field, the *true* force experienced by this is equal to total charge Times the macroscopic field, I think I'll be done. But this result may be wrong, and may not be easy to prove, for it too requires evaluation of weighted integrals inside integrals)

**So here are my questions**

1. Will the results given by macro and micro even be the same? I'm inclined to believe that it *is* the same, but it is no more than a gut feeling. I will keep trying to derive this result, but I really need help here.
2. If it is not the same, let's say, we some how know this from some calculation or by some experiment, then how good is the macroscopic result as an approximation? Does the laws of energy conservation still hold? If let's say I dispense the use of microscopic variables entirely, and now my world is fully defined by macroscopic variables (and suppose that the calculations that I do are also of that sort, **not** microscopic), then does all the laws of physics, mainly the energy conservation principle hold? If it does, then I'm fine with the macroscopic formulation.

For more information, on Rusakoff's averaging and the method of weighted averages:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0031891469900366

https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article/38/10/1188/1041160/A-Derivation-of-the-Macroscopic-Maxwell-Equations

Comment: > *"This discrete sum formula takes no hit when converted to the integral"* Not true - for point charges, potential $V_{micro}$ becomes divergent and the integral formula becomes invalid.

Comment: @JánLalinský ok, i should've noticed this. So it is only correct to write the integral when we assume everything is macroscopic, since the microscopic integral doesn't make physical sense? This has got to be a mathematical technicality right? If i now understand it right, at the end of the day the averaging that I do of the charge distribution, how small it is decides how accurate my energy result is?

Comment: The integral formula makes sense both in microscopic and macroscopic theory, if the charge distribution is regular enough, that means no point or line charges.

Comment: That the force on a charge in a field is proportional to both the charge and the field is a definition in the theory that is based on precision experimental tests. If this wouldn't be so, then the structure of the theory would have to be significantly different. That these formulas don't make any sense at the scale of an electron is well known... that's simply because the electron is not a charged object. If you want to understand what electrons "do", then you need quantum field theory.

Comment: "then how good is the macroscopic result as an approximation"? The Pioneer spacecraft was designed and launched more than 50 years ago and is now beyond the Solar system, in 1995 we could still receive useful data from it via RF comm link whose design was all based on the macroscopic Maxwell equations. Only the *invention* of the individual transistors/diodes needed QM but even that is debatable. Energy conservation based on Poynting's theorem is the underpinning of any and all RF communications link design *and* operation, see Friis's formula.

Answer (score 0):

To 1.: Will all results be the same in micro or macro? No, obviously. But those that matter on the macro scale will be the same in sufficiently good approximation.

One example of a result that differs in both formulations is the self-energy. You know that
$$
U = \frac{1}{2} \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \int \left(\sum_i \delta(r - r_i)\right) \left(\sum_j \frac{1}{\left|r-r_j\right|}\right) \text{d}V
$$
diverges, right? Because the self-energy of a single point charge is infinite. If you want a reasonable finite value, you'll be using
$$
U = \frac{1}{2} \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \int \left(\sum_{i\neq j} \delta(r - r_i) \frac{1}{\left|r-r_j\right|}\right) \text{d}V\,,
$$
which will not necessarily agree with
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int \rho_{macro} \phi_{macro} \text{d}V
$$
(to any order of approximation/at any radius of the averaging function). (Or you use the first one, which is infinite, while the macroscopic one isn't...)

To 2.: You can derive energy conservation from Maxwell's equations. The papers you reference show that Maxwell's equations are the same after averaging. So energy conservation holds in the macroscopic version. Where's the problem?

*Edit*: Let me add to the first point via an example. Consider averaging with a function that is constant in a spherical shell of radius $R$ (and normalized, of course). (cf. Russakoff, section II) This has the same effect as replacing all point charges with homogeneously charged spheres (which is an example that at least for one single charge allows easy calculation that you can do yourself).

The self-energy of each sphere will be some term proportional to $\frac{1}{R}$. Those are the $i=j$-contributions in the integral above. They are constants and, weirdly, depend on the radius of the averaging function (and diverge for $R\rightarrow 0$, i.e. when you make the averaging disappear). These terms are not very useful, which is a good reason for the $i \neq j$ in the sum.

If $R \ll \left|r_i - r_j\right|$, then using the averaging will give a small addition to the $i \neq j$-terms in the self-energy of the charge distribution, these are additions of order $\frac{R}{\left|r_i - r_j\right|}$. You'd sort of still be seeing single charges.

If $R > \left|r_i - r_j\right|$ (and in continuum mechanics, for example, indeed you average such that many particles are contained in an averaging volume, cf. the discussion by Rossakoff and his reference to de Groot and Mazur), then you stop distinguishing individual charges. You are sort of "smearing" them, and only seeing the dipole moments for pairs of positive and negative charges, for example - which macroscopically is the polarization of the material. So this indeed has an influence on the values of the self-energy, and also on its interpretation/what you can do with it; you are hiding some of the microscopic detail.
But if you intend to study the interaction between two macroscopic bodies (for example, one charged, one a dielectric), then this macroscopic self-energy is sufficiently accurate, while you've also hidden a sufficient amount of microscopic detail to make the problem treatable.

Comment: Ok, i didn't know about the fact that energy conservation can be derived from Maxwell's laws (i suppose it's in chapter 7 of Griffiths, while I'm in chapter 4). So let me get this clear, $$W=\frac{1}{2} \iiint \rho_{macro}V_{macro} d\tau $$ gives a good enough approximate result to the microscopic values, but these fundamentally differ, as the macro stuff don't contain self energy terms  whereas the micro ones do, right? I only wanted to know that this result is a good enough approx, and that all laws of physics stay intact in the macroscopic world.

Comment: The self-energy terms of the individual charges are a technicality (maybe I shouldn't have added this to the discussion... :) ). But the macroscopic and microscopic self energy also differ because you are sort of hiding microscopic detail. I've made an edit, perhaps this helps.

Comment: thank you for the edit. I'm now seeing this whole thing in a different light, the real world is ofcourse a bunch of non zero sized charges, so the point charge formulation definitely ought to give us wrong results. Now it sort of makes sense, in a way. The micro $\rho$ that we write, in reality would be non zero sized smear charges. I suppose then it doesn't make sense to even think about the point charge distributions? So then, ideally, we wouldn't write the microscopic charge density to be a summation of point charges would we?

Comment: No, the point charge is incredibly useful. If it actually has a size it is lower than $10^{-18}$m, distances between charges in a solid are somewhere between $10^{-12}$m and $10^{-10}$m and the averaging to obtain macroscopic quantities happens on scales larger than that. The point of the point charge is that you leave out unnecessary information: the charge is so small that on scales where you are using it including its size does not really change the results, but complicates the model and calculations. So you'd rather use a point.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Will the results given by macro and micro even be the same? I'm inclined to believe that it *is* the same, but it is no more than a gut feeling. I will keep trying to derive this result, but I really need help here.

Results of same formulae with different fields won't be the same, obviously.

It is hard to define macroscopic fields based on microscopic fields in such a way that macroscopic theory predictions will be the same as predictions of the microscopic theory.

For example, Poynting's density of EM energy in macroscopic theory will be different than in microscopic theory.

> 2. If it is not the same, let's say, we some how know this from some calculation or by some experiment, then how good is the macroscopic result as an approximation? Does the laws of energy conservation still hold? If let's say I dispense the use of microscopic variables entirely, and now my world is fully defined by macroscopic variables (and suppose that the calculations that I do are also of that sort, **not** microscopic), then does all the laws of physics, mainly the energy conservation principle hold? If it does, then I'm fine with the macroscopic formulation.

Macroscopic theory is an imperfect theory, in that it does not describe all microscopic details. But it does not have problem with energy conservation - one can define macroscopic density of EM energy and the corresponding flux in such a way that local conservation law (the Poynting theorem) holds.